# Integer to Binary in C

Tags: c, binary, converters

I am new to C programming and unsure what is wrong with my program. I am writing a program which takes an integer as an input and returns it in binary form.

An input of 43 would output 101011, but the output is 1.

Please advise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void printBinaryForm( int X )
//Purpose: Print parameter X in binary form
//Output: Binary representation of X directly printed
//Assumption: X is non-negative (i.e. >= 0)
{

    //[TODO] CHANGE this to your solution.
    
    int input = X;
    char output[] = "";
    char binary1 = '1';
    char binary2 = '0';
    
    while(input != 0){
        if(input%2 != 0){
            input = input - 1;
            strncat(output, &binary1, 1);
        }
        else{
            input /= 2;
            strncat(output, &binary2, 1);
        }
    }
       
    printf("%s",output);

}

int main(void)
{
    int X;  

    printf("Enter X: ");
    scanf("%d",&X);

    //print X in binary form
    printBinaryForm( X );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The most obvious problem is that `output` is an array of a single character, which is the null byte.  That means you have no room to store anything else in it.  The `strncat` calls are writing past the end of array, resulting in undefined behavior.

Comment: Turn warnings of your compiler on!

Comment: `strncat` requires a string, not a char.

Answer (score 1):

With integer values a *Right-Shift* is equivalent to dividing by two. So you can create your binary representation simply by shifting right and evaluating whether the resulting bit in memory is `1` or `0` and outputting the appropriate character, either `'1'` or `'0'`. A simple function for that would be:

```
/** unpadded binary representation of 'v'. */
void binprn (const unsigned long v)
{
    if (!v) {
        putchar ('0');
        return;
    };

    size_t sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;            /* get total bits in type */
    unsigned long rem = 0;

    while (sz--)                                /* loop sz number of times */
        if ((rem = v >> sz))                    /* while digits remain */
            putchar ((rem & 1) ? '1' : '0');    /* output '1' or '0' */
    
    /* note: the caller is responsible for adding the '\n' */
}
```

Then combining with your `main()` and adding validation of the input, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/** unpadded binary representation of 'v'. */
void binprn (const unsigned long v)
{
    if (!v) {
        putchar ('0');
        return;
    };

    size_t sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;            /* get total bits in type */
    unsigned long rem = 0;

    while (sz--)                                /* loop sz number of times */
        if ((rem = v >> sz))                    /* while digits remain */
            putchar ((rem & 1) ? '1' : '0');    /* output '1' or '0' */
    
    /* note: the caller is responsible for adding the '\n' */
}

int main (void) {
    
    int x;
    
    fputs ("enter x: ", stdout);                /* prompt for integer */
    if (scanf ("%d", &x) != 1) {                /* read/validate user-input */
        fputs ("error: invalid integer.\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    binprn (x);             /* output binary represntation of x */
    putchar ('\n');         /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

(**note:** the caller is responsible for newline control. There may be cases where you want to output several binary representations of numbers together before outputting the `'\n'` so that task is left for the calling function to carry out)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/binprn
enter x: 255
11111111
```

or

```
$ ./bin/binprn
enter x: 127
1111111
```

or

```
$ ./bin/binprn
enter x: 43690
1010101010101010
```

You can also adjust the logic to output a padded representation to X number of bits (4, 8, 16, 32, 64, etc...)

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.