# How to define an array of binary numbers in keil uVision?

Tags: arrays, c, binary-data, keil

I've tried putting suffix 'y' followed by binary numbers within an array in header file but "syntax error near 'y', expected '}'  " appear.

```
extern unsigned int A[8]={
00111100y, 
01100110y, 
01100110y, 
01111110y, 
01100110y, 
01100110y, 
01100110y};
```

[image]

Comment: Just enter the unsigned number -- the computer only knows binary, so it will store each number as `1`s` and `0`s in memory... When you use `printf()`, etc.. to view the decimal representation, you are just viewing the stored binary in a different base. But if you like, you are using the syntax correctly, e.g. [Binary, Decimal, HEX, and Octal Constants](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_db_exp_constants.htm)

Comment: But you are NOT using the syntax correctly in your pictures you posted. The `','` operator is not doing what you think, and there is no provision for adding `\\` to numbers.

Comment: I'm using it for embedded system, I don't want to print it. I could have used the corresponding decimal numbers, but I want a mapped character for 8by8 matrix shape. Just ignore the first array, what about the rest?

Comment: Your error comes from `smiley[8]` -- your initializer has `16` elements ... If you want the character representation of the binary form, then just loop over the bits in the number shifting from `sizeof(type) - 1` to `0` and output `putchar (val >> shift ? '1' : '0');` to output the binary representation (or store the result in a character array -- nul-terminated if you use it as a string) See [Printing Binary Representation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63534730/3422102)

Comment: Note, to output the full-padded representation, remove the check on `rem` in the example above.

Comment: What is your intention with `\\...` ? Is it meant to be a comment? Try `//...`, or better `/* ... */`.

Comment: Please explain what you think the "y" does. -- Even the C17 standard has no format to write literals in binary. Some compilers might extend this, for example GCC with the `0b` prefix. I don't know for the Keil compiler you are using. -- Your best bet is to use hexadecimal numbers and a comment to show the bits.

Comment: What is your intention with `00000000y`? Is it meant to be a literal number? Better try one of the ancient normal forms, like `0x00`.

Comment: Please do not show pictures of code. Provide textual information in text form directly here please.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to declare (in contrast to define) an array AND initialise it immediatly. That is unusual. Do you get the same error if you remoce the `extern`, in order to turn the shon lines temporarily into definitions instead of declarations?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], directly here, in text form. It would make things so much easier and allow potential answerers to try things on their own instead of asking you to try.

Answer (score 0):

The errors in the picture of text can be solved by:

- using correct commenting snytax : `/* ... */` (intentionally providing the ancient form)
- using correct number syntax: `66 /* decimal */` or `0x42 /* hexadecimal */`
- not using the suffix y, which is not needed for format proposed above

Some more errors (not shown above, but more likely traps to get caught in):

- avoiding numbers which start with 0 (not mentioned in the shown errors, but another trap)
- in the header only declare the arrays: using `extern` but no `= numbers;`
- somewhere in the code define the arrays: NOT using `extern`, but `= numbers;`

Answer (score 0):

the posted syntax is not correct.

Cannot declare something as `extern` AND initialize it in the same statement.

Note: `extern` generally means the actual declaration is on another file ) which will be linked with the current file.

Suggest:  in the current file:

```
extern unsigned int smiley[8];
```

and in some other file:

```
unsigned int smiley[8] =
{
    0, // 00000000
    1, // 00000001
};
```

Notice the use of braces '{' and '}', not parens '(' ')'.

Notice the correct 'slant' (top toward right) of the slashes at the beginning of the comments.

the `y` is not part of the standard C syntax.  Perhaps it is an extension in the kyle compiler.  However, in researching the kyle compiler documentation I did not find a `y` data type.

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time.. but all the fixes you have mentioned are known to me and works fine with decimal numbers. My concern is to write array of binary numbers like    `` unsigned char A[]={ 01101100, 00110110} ``    . In keil binay specifier is 'y' as suffix and '0' as prefix is octal specifier. So if I write `01101100y` there's a conflict for compiler whether the number binary or octal. So I can't find other ways to specify binary numbers followed by zero. That's what I want a solution to...

Comment: suggest: `1101100y` and, if necessary, can do a couple of shifts left then right to assure that upper bit is 0.  Note, should define that numbers as 'unsigned char''